# Removing "1, " and "2, " from a string with out removing "11, " and "12, "

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have a column of strings that can contain 1-15 in a comma separated list (e.g. "`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15`" or "`2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15`" or "`1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15`")

How do I remove the "1, " and the "2, " from all examples above?

already tried:

```
Replace(Replace(@code, "1, ", "")@code, "2, ", "")
Trim(@code)
```

Initially was thinking to use the replace function but doing so also removes the "1, " and "2, " from "11, " and "12, ".

What are other techniques that can be used here?

Comment: Fix the design and don't store delimited data. Then the solution is a simple `DELETE`: `DELETE FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE YourNormalisedColumn IN (1,2);`

Comment: I would agree with @ThomA here.  I also see storing delimited data is a sql anti-pattern on design.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Its a good question though, things like this happen in the real world

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mention in the comments the real solution is to fix your design.

Let's create a quick sample dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable(ID int IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY,
                           SomeInt int NOT NULL,
                           SomeDate date NULL,
                           YourDenormalisedColumn varchar(8000) NOT NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (SomeInt,
                           SomeDate,
                           YourDenormalisedColumn)
VALUES(24,GETDATE(),'1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15'),
      (117,NULL,'2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15'),
      (3,'20231117','1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15');
```

Creating and `INSERT`ing the data is actually quite simple, we just `CREATE` the minimal detail of the table we need and then use `STRING_SPLIT` to insert the new data. Then we can `DROP` the old denormalised column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.NormalisedData (ArbitraryID int IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_NormalisedData PRIMARY KEY,
                                 YourID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_NormalisedData_YourTable_YourID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.YourTable(ID),
                                 NormalisedValue int NOT NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.NormalisedData (YourID,
                                NormalisedValue)
SELECT YT.ID,
       SS.value
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(YT.YourDenormalisedColumn,',') SS;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable DROP COLUMN YourDenormalisedColumn;
```

Now we have a normalised dataset your requirement is easy, it's just a simple `DELETE`:

```sql
DELETE FROM dbo.NormalisedData
WHERE NormalisedValue IN (1,2);
```

---

If you are adamant you can't change your design (you can, should, and must), then you *could* split the string, remove the "offending" values, and then re-aggregate:

```
--Run before the COLUMN is DROPed
UPDATE YT
SET YT.YourDenormalisedColumn = (SELECT STRING_AGG(SS.value,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ss.ordinal)
                                 FROM STRING_SPLIT(YT.YourDenormalisedColumn,',',1) SS
                                 WHERE TRIM(ss.value) NOT IN ('1','2')) --TRIM because you have leading spaces and ' 1' <> '1'
FROM dbo.YourTable YT;
```

---

```sql
--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.NormalisedData;
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-dOfE6nk)

Answer (score 3):

The correct thing to do would be to stop using delimited strings.

For more information, Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

However I know sometimes changing the database structure is impossible even if it is the correct thing to do - so a workaround would be to include the delimiter in the first argument of the `replace` and then trim it back out.

First, create and populate sample table(**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE TableName (
  Id int identity(1,1) ,
  DelimitedValues varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO TableName (DelimitedValues) VALUES
('1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15'), 
('2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15'), 
('1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15');
```

The update statement:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET DelimitedValues = TRIM(', ' FROM 
  REPLACE(', '+ DelimitedValues +', ', ', 1, ', ', '))
WHERE Id < 3;
```

A quick select to make sure the update was successful:

```
SELECT Id, DelimitedValues
FROM TableName
```

Results:

| Id | DelimitedValues |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 |
| 2 | 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 |
| 3 | 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 |

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>db<>fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/VkWNJ1TS)

Comment: At first I was confused as to why the third row of results has a 1, but then I realised the query has `Id < 3` (someone keeps deleting this comment but I believe it is a useful comment)

Answer (score 2):

edit: after typing all this out, I see its similar to the answer Thom A already gave except I'm using CTEs instead of creating tables.

You can use STRING_SPLIT to pivot the csv field into proper data, then process that data, then use STRING_AGG to unpivot it back into a csv field.

STRING_SPLIT was introduced in SQL Server 2016
STRING_AGG was introduced in SQL Server 2017

For example if your key is MyPrimaryKey and the field with the CSV data is called CsvField you can split it out like this:

```
select t.MyPrimaryKey, LTRIM(RTRIM(split.value)) as split_out
from MyTable t
    cross apply STRING_SPLIT(t.CsvField,',') as split
```

This will give you separate rows for each value like this:

```
MyPrimaryKey split_out
------------ ---------
one          2
one          3
one          4
one          5
one          6
two          1
two          2
     etc...
```

Once you've got it in that format, you can easily remove the values you dont want, using something like this:

```
with cteStageOne as (
    select t.MyPrimaryKey, LTRIM(RTRIM(split.value)) as split_out
    from MyTable t
        cross apply STRING_SPLIT(t.CsvField,',') as split
)
select *
from cteStageOne
where split_out not in ('1','2')
```

Here's a complete solution that re-aggregates the strings back together:

```
with cteStageOne as (
    select t.MyPrimaryKey, LTRIM(RTRIM(split.value)) as split_out
    from MyTable t
        cross apply STRING_SPLIT(t.CsvField,',') as split
), cteStageTwo as (
    select MyPrimaryKey, split_out
    from cteStageOne
    where split_out not in ('1','2')
)
select MyPrimaryKey, STRING_AGG(split_out,', ') as recombine
from cteStageTwo
group by MyPrimaryKey
```